# Looking for circuitry to save power on an I2C sensor

Tags: mosfet, sensor, i2c, low-power

I have an I2C sensor connected to a microcontroller. The whole system is battery powered, so I need to find ways to switch off power from devices when they are not in use.

For the sensor, I am thinking of using an IO Expander or something similar to disconnect the sensor from Vcc. But what to do with the I2C pins? They are pulled up with 10 kΩ resistors.

Even though I am disconnecting the sensor from the power, there will be still current flowing through the pull-up resistors. Is there a way to also disconnect SDA and SCL pins, so that the sensor is not drawing any current at all when not in use?

I am considering using MOSFETs as switches, but wondering if there are any standard solutions or best practices.

Comment: What is the sensor?

Comment: And what's the microcontroller? Some can actually disable the pins so they float without no current.

Comment: @pipe The MCU and it being able to disable pins is irrelevant, if you turn off I2C slave supply and have external pull-up resistors to some supply.

Comment: It's a temperature and humidity sensor SHT30. In terms of the microcontroller, same circuitry should be used in two different systems - one powered by nRF52840 and another one by ESP32-WROOM32.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are going to turn the sensor supply on and off, put the I2C pull-up resistors on the sensor supply so they turn on and off with the sensor.

This will prevent leakage through resistors to sensor.

It also prevents problems of bus voltage ever being higher than sensor supply, during switching things on or off.

Answer (score 5):

A common answer is that you connect the I2c pull ups to an IO pin. When you are using the sensor the IO pin is high providing pull up, but when in powere down it is low with no current through the pullup.

You can also consider active I2C pullup chips, many of which have a power down pin to reduce current consumption.

Comment: It can be the same IO pin to turn power on/off, or instead of IO pin, just put the pull-ups on the switched power so there is no situation where bus would power the sensor or bus voltage higher than sensor.

Comment: @Justme absolutely agree on the range of options.

Answer (score 1):

One simple option would be to use an N-channel MOSFET as a switch to connect/disconnect the IC to/from Ground instead of VCC. Just make sure any pins that connect to ground only do so through the same switch

Comment: Disconnecting the ground is usually the least suitable option, and an option which I will never recommend, but at least you made sure to mention the limitations under which it is possible.

Comment: When comparing your solution with the one above (connecting pull ups with the sensor power that will be switched off), what are the advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: @user14665305 If you only have supply, ground, and I2C bus to a one single chip, it does not make a lot of difference. But disconnecting ground while you have data wires between two systems is in general something that has some dangers you might not realize until it is too late. For instance in this case, if you leave supply connected and disconnect ground, you must not pull the SDA or SCL low, or the sensor IC will be powered through data bus. It is just less likely by accident if you turn off the supply. It is easier to think 0V as the reference idle/unpowered state than 3.3V.